# Having a UISwitch respond to method defined as a protocol

Tags: protocols, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch that is in side my UIView. I would like the UISwitch to use a method that I defined in the protocol, and then have another class use the method. This is my first time trying to use a protocol, and I can't seem to figure out how to link up my UISwitch to the method call in the protocol.

This is my protocol:

```
@protocol responderForOptionalSwitch <NSObject>
@required
- (IBAction) onOffSwitch:(id)sender;
@end
```

But this method doesn't show up under received actions in the connections inspector.

Answer (score 0):

A protocol is a list of methods that an object should (or, in some cases, must) implement. It is not an implementation of your method itself. To see it show up in IB, you should implement the method in the view/controller (the .h/.m) that your switch belongs to (i.e.: what xib is it in?).

Comment: I'm using storyboards, and the switch is in the custom UIView. But I have the onOffSwitch method defined in the ViewController that the UIView is nested in. I understand you don't implement them in the protocol, but shouldn't I be able to drag connect my switch to that method in the protocol? So for instance I thought I would be able to drag from my switch to the onOffSwtich method in my protocol.